# Is a double-touch in beach volleyball OK as long as it's part of one action?

Tags: rules, beach-volleyball

There was the [same question for indoor volleyball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/double-hit-in-volleyball), but in the case of beach volleyball:

> If the other team pass, set, hits it over to me and I kick it and then
>   it hits my chest (but it's only one action/motion) would that count as
>   a double hit fault?
>
> What about if the other team attacks it and I go to set set it and it
>   slips thru my fingers and bounces off my head but it's only one action
>   on my part?

Answer (score 2):

The rule you need here is 9.2.3.1 in the [2015-2016 beach volleyball rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB_BeachVolleyball_Rules_2015-2016_EN_V3_20150205.pdf):

> at the first hit of the team, unless it is played overhand using fingers
>   (exception Rule 9.2.2.1), the ball may contact various parts of the body
>   consecutively, provided that the contacts occur during one action.

This means that the first example (kicking and then hitting the chest) is not a fault as it was part of one action. However, this exception does *not* apply to an attempt to play the ball overhand, so the second example (attempting to set and then hitting the face) would be a fault.

Note that even if the attempt to set were successful, that would likely be called a fault due to how the "catch" and "double touch" rules are interpreted in beach volleyball.

Comment: Also, if it was a hard-driven attack, you can receive overhand and you can even _hold_ the ball _momentarily_ and it would not be a catch fault.

Comment: I know - but I don't think I've *ever* seen an example of that rule being applied.

Comment: Oh, I believe it is applied all the time, almost every time a hard-driven attack is received overhand. In this situation, the player is allowed to stop the ball by slightly “squeezing” it in hands or going down and up with the ball a bit. (Otherwise, it would be really hard to control the ball. But in other situations, that would be a catch.) I am unable to find a good real-life video example on YouTube, only a mention of this in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTS917r8XVg